Coefficients of DFT
I am studying Fourier series and DFT algorithm. By definition, given a sequence of real or complex numbers $(x_n)_{n=0,...,N-1}$, with $N\geq 1$, its discrete Fourier transformation is defined as the sequence $(y_n)_{n=0,...,N-1}$ where:
\begin{equation*}
y_n=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x_ke^{-\frac{2\pi i}{N}kn}
\end{equation*}
for all $n=0,...,N-1$.
Now, I am trying to show that then
\begin{equation*}
x_n=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}y_ke^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}kn}
\end{equation*}
I tried to proceed by induction: the case $N=1$ is trivial, for $N=2$ we observe that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix} y_0 \\ y_1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
, so we obtain the thesis just inverting the matrix. However, from this point on, I do not know how to deal with the general case $N\geq 3$; for example, I do not know how to show that the corresponding matrix ha determinant $N$.
Do you have any ideas or suggestion?
Thanks in advance for your help!

This topic is extensively expressed in books, webs, .... Take a look at for instance https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41389/magic-of-twiddle-factor-in-dft or https://technobyte.org/twiddle-factors-dsp-dft-fft-idft/.

Instead of via induction, proceed directly.
